# Pandas перебор строк с условиям

Tags: python, pandas

Задача: сопоставить план и объем в заказах по колонке merge (внести в таблицу планов колонку с объемом из заказов).

План для каждого клиента ставится свой и на разных уровнях.

Например, у одного клиента может быть "год+квартал+бренд+тип бизнеса", у другого "год+квартал+код адреса доставки+бренд+тип бизнеса" и тд.
Вариаций может быть много исходя из колонок в таблице Планы

Помогите в df_Orders добавить колонку merge на основе df_Plans. Чтобы для каждого клиента в Orders (KSSS_cust) в колонке merge было свое значение

---

Есть 2 DataFrame:

1. Планы клиентов [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
df_plans = pd.DataFrame([{'Year': 2023, 'Qtr': 1, 'Mnth': 1, 'KSSS_cust': 3514453, 'KSSS_Shipto': "", 'Brand': "ABD", 'LoB': "B2B", 'Segment': "", 'Product_group': "", 'Product_Name': "", 'Pack_group2': "", 'Production': "", 'Plan': 1500},
                         {'Year': 2023, 'Qtr': 1, 'Mnth': 1, 'KSSS_cust': 3485839, 'KSSS_Shipto': 3491202, 'Brand': "ABD", 'LoB': "B2C", 'Segment': "", 'Product_group': "", 'Product_Name': "", 'Pack_group2': "", 'Production': "", 'Plan': 10000}])
```

2. Заказы тех же клиентов с таким же набором колонок, только вместо плана "объем"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
df_Orders = pd.DataFrame([{'Year': 2023, 'Qtr': 1, 'Mnth': 1, 'KSSS_cust': 3514453, 'KSSS_Shipto': "", 'Ord_N': 1235669, 'Product_N': 6548, 'Brand': "ABD", 'LoB': "B2B", 'Segment': "", 'Product_group': "", 'Product_Name': "", 'Pack_group2': "", 'Production': "", 'Volume': 3200},
                          {'Year': 2023, 'Qtr': 1, 'Mnth': 1, 'KSSS_cust': 3485839, 'KSSS_Shipto': 3491202, 'Ord_N': 2548569, 'Product_N': 85486, 'Brand': "ABD", 'LoB': "B2C", 'Segment': "", 'Product_group': "", 'Product_Name': "", 'Pack_group2': "", 'Production': "", 'Volume': 5600},
                          {'Year': 2023, 'Qtr': 1, 'Mnth': 1, 'KSSS_cust': 3514453, 'KSSS_Shipto': "", 'Ord_N': "", 'Product_N': 587526, 'Brand': "ABD", 'LoB': "B2B", 'Segment': "", 'Product_group': "", 'Product_Name': "", 'Pack_group2': "", 'Production': "", 'Volume': 1560}])
```

Код клиента = 'KSSS_cust',
код адреса доставки = 'KSSS_Shipto'

---

Я смогла получить названия не пустых колонок в df_Plans для каждого клиента.

Не могу понять, как перебрать строки в Заказах и добавить колонку merge для каждой строки с условием совпадения названия колонок для конкретного клиента из Планов

Т.е. в обоих DataFrame должна появиться колонка merge с своим содержимым для каждого клиента:

merge в df_Plans:

- клиент1 : 2023_1_1_3514453_ABD_B2B
- клиент2 : 2023_1_1_3485839_3491202_ABD_B2C

merge в df_Orders:

- строка1+клиент1 : 2023_1_1_3514453_ABD_B2B
- строка2+клиент2 : 2023_1_1_3485839_3491202_ABD_B2C
- строка3+клиент1 : 2023_1_1_3514453_ABD_B2B

вот так я получаю названия не пустых колонок в df_Plans:

```
for ksss in bonus_pl_cust:
        ksss = int(ksss)
        cust_pl_merge = bonus_plans[(bonus_plans['KSSS_cust'] == ksss)]
        nan_value = float("NaN")
        cust_pl_merge.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
        cust_pl_merge.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
        cust_cols = list(cust_pl_merge.columns)
        cust_cols = cust_cols[:-2]
```

Я пробовала через .apply и доп.функцию, но выдает ошибку, что элемент cust_cols не передается в функцию

```
for ksss in bonus_pl_cust:
        ksss = int(ksss)
        cust_pl_merge = bonus_plans[(bonus_plans['KSSS_cust'] == ksss)]
        nan_value = float("NaN")
        cust_pl_merge.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
        cust_pl_merge.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
        cust_cols = list(cust_pl_merge.columns)
        cust_cols = cust_cols[:-2]
        df['merge'] = df.apply(check_merge(cust_cols), axis=1)


def check_merge(row, cust_cols):
    row['merge'] = ''

    for clmn in cust_cols:
        row['merge'] = row['merge'] + row[clmn]
    return row['merge']
```

Comment: Во-первых, опишите нормально задачу: пока что вы описываете свои действия для достижения неведомой нам цели; и по таблице не понятно, откуда вы берете идентификаторы клиентов.. Во-вторых, почему пример исходных данных в виде скриншота?

Comment: @strawdog обновила, надеюсь теперь понятнее

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что 1) вам нужно собрать в строку непустые значения значения в первом дадафрейме, 2) эти значения внести во второй в соответствии с номером клиента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то все решается довольно просто:

Сначала получаем колонку merge из непустых значений df_plans:

```
df_plans = df_plans.assign(merge=df_plans.apply(lambda x: "_".join([str(y) for y in x[:-1] if y]), axis=1))
```

```
   Year  Qtr  Mnth  KSSS_cust KSSS_Shipto Brand  LoB Segment Product_group Product_Name Pack_group2 Production   Plan                             merge
0  2023    1     1    3514453               ABD  B2B                                                             1500          2023_1_1_3514453_ABD_B2B
1  2023    1     1    3485839     3491202   ABD  B2C                                                            10000  2023_1_1_3485839_3491202_ABD_B2C
```

затем делаем merge с df_Orders по нужным нам колонкам:

```
df_Orders = pd.merge(df_Orders, df_plans[['KSSS_cust','merge']],on='KSSS_cust', how="left")
```

```
   Year  Qtr  Mnth  KSSS_cust KSSS_Shipto    Ord_N  Product_N Brand  LoB Segment Product_group Product_Name Pack_group2 Production  Volume                             merge
0  2023    1     1    3514453              1235669       6548   ABD  B2B                                                              3200          2023_1_1_3514453_ABD_B2B
1  2023    1     1    3485839     3491202  2548569      85486   ABD  B2C                                                              5600  2023_1_1_3485839_3491202_ABD_B2C
2  2023    1     1    3514453                          587526   ABD  B2B                                                              1560          2023_1_1_3514453_ABD_B2B
```